# How to remove background blur from SwiftUI Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker

In SwiftUI, Segmented Pickers (Pickers with `SegmentedPickerStyle())` ) come default with a blur in the background of each item. Is there a way to remove this?

[image]

As you can see, option2 has a gray blur behind it, and it isn't selected. I'm trying to get it so that the background would blend into the view behind it. I've tried `(.background(Color.clear))`, but the background is seemingly applied *over* the gray blur.

Comment: It is not background it is a designated part of system standard control. If you don't like it - create custom, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/70834641/12299030, and configure it whichever you want.

Comment: You can change background color in Segmented Pickers @Charlie Reeder

Comment: @Fatemeh You're right, thanks. However, the blur remains, so I'm trying to get the background color without the blur.

Comment: It is not background color with blur, so it is default or system standard of Segment Picker @CharlieReeder